# How to auto start chromium after boot on the Raspberry 2 (2015-01-31 debian wheezy)?

Tags: boot, chromium

I tried this tutorial on the latest debian wheezy (2015-01-31)
http://www.lukebrowning.com/hardware/raspberry-pi/touch-screen-chromium-kiosk-on-the-raspberry-pi/
but its not working anymore...
(If I made the same thing on an older debian wheezy (2014-06). Its working fine.
What I should modify?

Comment: have you looked at these http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=kiosk also what specifically isn't working

Comment: Yes, first I red theese questions but too old question and didnt solved my problem. I think something changed with in the new debian wheezy, but iam not sure

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It appears there is now a different autostart file to use located in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

To get Chromium to autostart follow these instructions

1. Type

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart"
   ```
2. Add the following line:

   ```
   /usr/bin/chromium --kiosk --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-restore-session-state "http://www.domain.com"
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>y</kbd>
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Worked for me!

Comment: On Raspbian Jessie add this line `@/usr/bin/chromium --kiosk --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-restore-session-state "http://www.domain.com"` to `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` instead

Comment: As I understand it, Chromium is now Chromium Browser so you need `@/usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-restore-session-state www.domain.com` in the `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`. I also had to remove the quotes and http to get it to work.

Comment: The `--ignore-certificate-errors` also produced warnings when Chromium opened up. Otherwise, works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you so much for the `--disable-restore-session-state` flag. Was looking for that for ages!