# Auto start Chromium and Ekiga on startup

Tags: raspbian

I've followed this post :

[How to auto start chromium after boot on the Raspberry 2 (2015-01-31 debian wheezy)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27572/how-to-auto-start-chromium-after-boot-on-the-raspberry-2-2015-01-31-debian-whee?newreg=1e2ece973cea416fbf0dca51e38b2aec)

I've added the two following lines to the autostart file referenced there

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
/usr/bin/ekiga
```

Both those commands work from the terminal but nothing on startup.

Two questions arise from this.

- Any thoughts on why it isn't working
- How can I monitor/log/track what may or may not be working with this?

Answer (score 1):

to get `Chromium` and `ekiga` to start at login on a per user basis I needed to do the following

```
> nano /home/user/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

then add the following lines:

```
@/usr/bin/chromium-browser --command-line-options
@/usr/bin/ekiga
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you use a distro with installed LXDE? Otherwise this autostart file location is wrong.

LXDE/KDE/Gnome all are different, what desktop enviroment did you use?

(you can even try to use cron via crontab for this with the @reboot flag)

Comment: I'm just using stock raspbian. The file /LXDE-pi/autostart already existed and had entries in it (eg @lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi) so I assumed that LXDE was already there.