# NetworkManager: Failed to start on raspberrypi

Tags: raspbian, networkmanager

My NetworkManager has suddenly stopped working on my raspberry pi due to which I am  unable to connect to it either via putty or http. 
Configuration: I run a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Raspbian. It is also running hassio on docker.
Everything was running smoothly and I have not make any changes to the Pi. I was only fiddling with my router trying to change some wifi settings and my Pi went incommunicado. 
When the pi boots up it gives the following error:

```
NetworkManager has failed to start
```

`journalctl -xe` gives the following error:

```
hassio systemmd[6862]: NetworkManager.service: Failed at step EXEC
spawing /usr/sbin/NetworkManager: Exec format eror


pi@hassio:/usr/sbin $ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
â NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-09-08 17:00:35 IST; 18min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
  Process: 497 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 497 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
      CPU: 20ms

Sep 08 17:00:34 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 08 17:00:34 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 08 17:00:35 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 08 17:00:35 hassio systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Sep 08 17:00:35 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 08 17:00:35 hassio systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
Sep 08 17:00:35 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 08 17:00:35 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

pi@hassio:/usr/sbin $ journalctl --boot --unit=NetworkManager.service
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 22:46:43 IST, end at Sun 2019-09-08 17:20:01 IST. --
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Sep 08 17:00:33 hassio systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
```

It retries a few times and then gives up. 
Can somebody help me troubleshoot this please. What else would be of value to see in the configs?

Comment: Exec format error means that file is not executable. Does it have the executable permission set, what do you see from `file /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`, and if it's a script does the text look sane?

Comment: Raspbian DOES NOT use Network Manager so you need to explain why and what you did

Comment: Please edit your question and add the uncrippled output of these commands to it: `systemctl status NetworkManager.service` and `journalctl --boot --unit=NetworkManager.service`

Comment: @Ingo , I have put the info you asked for.

Comment: I found the issue to be something with my router. The IP address my pi has been using is somehow causing an issue. If I change the IP then things run fine although this error is still there in the logs. Not sure if this affects me in anyway though.
To your question @jdonald the file has execute permissions:

`pi@hassio:/usr/sbin $ ls -ltr NetworkManager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2095580 Nov  2  2018 NetworkManager `

@m , Maybe this error was always there, its just that I noticed it now, so I cant be sure what changed to cause this.

Comment: *"I have not make any changes to the Pi"* -> Clearly you did, since as Milliways points out Raspbian does not use NetworkManager by default.  If you have enabled it, you should probably disable `dhcpcd`.

Comment: Please have a look at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92175/79866 about error "*code=exited, status=203/EXEC*".

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on new rpi5 after reboot hangig in console must press shfit and then wait and again esc to come up, but ssh dosen't work anymore .. no idea atm.. (all on new image 64bit)