# execute my program when my Raspberry Pi boots up with time sleep 10

Tags: raspbian-buster

I am trying to execute my program when my Raspberry Pi boots up with time sleep 10.

it workt only with time sleep:
"time sleep 10 && ./DotNetConsoleApps/Tinkerforge/helloweatherstation"
[image]

but it didn´t work when i try to start it on the Raspberry boot.
Like this: 
"@reboot time sleep 10 && ./DotNetConsoleApps/Tinkerforge/helloweatherstation"
[image]
I need your help please

Comment: This question is not Pi specific.  I suggest you search for crontab and make a crontab entry.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but i have already tried crontab and no Autostart after i reboot the Raspberry.

Comment: like this crontab -e

Comment: `@reboot` isn't a linux command

Comment: You need to sort out why crontab did not work.   If you look through starting programs at boot questions you should soon find an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a script at bootup : Good practices?, rc.local falling, Other options?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85782/running-a-script-at-bootup-good-practices-rc-local-falling-other-options)

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question. And please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: Perhaps stating the obvious - but you entered `@reboot` on the Linux command line; that simply isn’t a Linux command. It might work in some other context, but here it means nothing. Also, in the other screenshot, `time` at the start of the command doesn’t really do anything except report how long the command took to run - but you already knew that was going to be very close to 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Your comments suggest that you've tried using an `@reboot` command in your `crontab`. The syntax you've used might be an issue. You might try again using the following syntax:

```
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /full/path/to/your/app  > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)
```

See [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105326/83790) if you need an explanation of this statement.