# Autostarting Chromium (Edit: How to connect to the local Session on Pi?)

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-3b+, remote, chromium

I just want to auto start Chromium on boot and I followed Method 1 over at
[this site](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-autostart-apps-in-rasbian-lxde-desktop/).
The same Method is used in the [Top Answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27572/how-to-auto-start-chromium-after-boot-on-the-raspberry-2-2015-01-31-debian-whee) here.

All in all it is about adding the command for starting the programm to

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

with

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

the command, that worked for me is adding

```
@/usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-restore-session-state www.domain.com
```

I am only using the Pi over Remote Desktop and when I reboot and connect I can see Chromium in the Taskmanager, but not on the Desktop. I also know, that it works, because I used a website from which I get notified when I visit it, but when I connect to the Pi via Remote I can not see the Chromium Window. Is there any way to not opening a new session or something?

I am really new to Linux and help would be appreciated :)

Greetings

Comment: What is *Method 1*? Please give us the relevant information without pointing us to visit a link to understand your question.

Comment: @Ingo Sorry it was really dumb to just paste the link! I just edited my question, so that it is instantly visible what I have done and what was on the site.

Comment: "*Remote Desktop*" means connecting from a MS Windows PC using **rdp** protocol? Or do you mean default **VNC**?

Comment: I did not know what VNC is, but I just found an answer that looks pretty promising I will try it soon, it uses VNC. https://askubuntu.com/a/240013/878452 And yes, my aim is to connect from a Windows PC to a Pi in my basement.

Comment: @Ingo I tried to follow the answer over at askubuntu.com/a/240013/878452 which is to use VNC with VINO to connect to the local session, but it was impossible for me to access 'vino-preferences' so I do not know any further. When I tried to connect without editing in 'vino-preferences' I got a 'VNC error - problem connecting'. Any advice?

Comment: If you login over your Remote Desktop connection can you launch & run Chromium manually? How about if you remove the `--kiosk` option from your autostart line, doe that work?

Comment: @RogerJones I now know, that not starting Chromium is the problem, but the problem is, that I am not able to remotely connect to the local session on the Pi. Instead, I am just connecting to a new session which is a new user with a new Desktop with of course no Windows of another user on it. My problem now is how to connect to a local session. I tried what is described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/240013/878452, but like I said above it sadly did not work.

Comment: In that case, unless you have a reason to avoid VNC, I'd suggest giving VNC a go to connect to the running desktop: here's a [guide](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/raspberry-pi.html)

Comment: @RogerJones The guide actually worked and I was able to see the Chromium Windows that is automatically started on boot. The problem is the screen resolution that VNC Viewer gives me is absolutely unusable and the Windows do not even fit the stream so I can not close windows or do anything. Is there any way to use VNC with Microsoft Remote Desktop instead of VNC Viewer, because with MC remote desktop I get perfect stream and res? I followed this Guide: http://www.intellamech.com/RaspberryPi-projects/rpi_vnc_rdp.html , but it did not work sadly. Anyways thank you for the help!